# Export-CSV exports length but not name

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have this code that I am running from powershell. When I run it without the export-csv i get all the folder names on the screen.

```
dir | select -expand fullname | % { ($_ -split '\')[7]
```

But if I add `| export-csv c:\test.txt` then I see following in the file not the folder name I expected just like I see it on the screen.

```
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"13"
"18"
"20"
"22"
"29"
"21"
"24"
"11"
"17"
"20"
"20"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Export-Csv` exports a table of object properties and their values.  Since your script is producing string objects, and the only property they have is length, that's what you got.

If you just want to save the list, use `Out-File` or `Set-Content` instead of `Export-Csv`.

Comment: I also added | out-file "C:\TEST.TXT" -Append . Thanks

Comment: I was getting length in my csv file. Turns out in the function I was calling it had  some text in speech marks when I removed that the csv started returning the objects properly.

Answer (score 35):

The previous answer does work, but what if someone was looking to output it into a CSV file.

This does **NOT** work:

```
$str_list = @('Mark','Henry','John')
$str_list | Export-Csv .\ExportStrList.csv -NoType
```

Because `Export-Csv` takes Objects and outputs properties. The only properties for a String[ ] is Length, so the CSV file only contains Lengths.

To fix this we need to change the String[ ] into an Object[ ]. The simplest way is with `Select-Object`.

Put each String into the Name property of a new Object[ ], like this:

```
$str_list = @('Mark','Henry','John')
$obj_list = $str_list | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}}
$obj_list | Export-Csv .\ExportStrList.csv -NoType
```

Just to re-iterate, `Select-Object` outputs a custom PSObject that can easily be manipulated. This is very powerful information, use it wisely.

Comment: This line was the most helpfull for me - $obj_list = $str_list | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}}.

Comment: That actually makes sense reading that.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
$data = @()
$row = New-Object PSObject
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "name1" -Value "Test"
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "name2" -Value 2
$data += $row

$data | Export-Csv "Text.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to handle this issue:

1. Out-File outputs by default

Define the master array list

```
$MASTER_ARRAY_LIST =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
```

Define the output filename

```
$OutputFilename="C:\TEMP\MyOutputFile.csv"

ForEach ( $Something in $List_of_Somethings) {
    $CURRENT_RECORD_DETAILS = New-Object PSObject -Property @{'name'=$($Something.Name);'fullname'=$($Something.FullName);'id'=$($Something.ID)}
    $MASTER_ARRAY_LIST.Add( $CURRENT_RECORD_DETAILS ) > $null
}

$MASTER_ARRAY_LIST.ToArray() | Select-Object -Property name,fullname,id | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You're replying to a 6 year old question so it would be great if you could add some more detail than just 'this is another way'. If it's better than any of the previous answers, can you explain why?

Comment: Also please format your answer. Use proper font sizes, proper use of bold and put your code into code blocks

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = @("test1","test2","test3")
$test | export-csv "firstTry.csv"
#We see that this fails. So here is how to to do it with the desired results

foreach ($item in $test) {
  [ pscustomobject]@{ ResultColumn = $item } | Export-Csv -Path ./secondTry.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles on this, the easiest solution is to remove the "-expand" from

`dir | select -expand fullname | % { ($_ -split '\')[7]`

the "-expand", as mentioned in other answers removes the property header from the fullname field, so there is now only a length property - no longer a fullname property. So, the export-csv exports the length as it is the only remaining property.

Comment: You might want to provide the altered version of the script to use in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to perform all the necessary flow of instructions, convert the output to csv format and finally pipe it with Out-File.

```
... | Select-Object Name,Date | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -Path Output.csv
```

This way you keep the initial format, convert it to a csv format and with that structure send it with the same format to a simple output file.

Answer (score -4):

```
$output |Select-Object * | Export-Csv 'h:\filename.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value