# export-csv error - an empty pipe element is not allowed

Tags: powershell, scripting, powercli

hopefully a quick and easy one here...

i have the following script that checks a particular vlan ID and then shows me the VMs that are using that ID

```
foreach($vm in (get-vm)){
if (Get-NetworkAdapter -vm $vm.name |?{$_.NetworkName -eq "vlan13_VM"}){$vm.name} | export-csv -path c:\scripts\vlans.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

i have added the export-csv command at the end as id like the details to be put into a csv which i can then email (will try to script the email part after)

i cant get the export-csv option to create the csv file as it comes back with an error saying

**An empty pipe element is not allowed at c:\scripts\checkvlan.ps1:2 char84**

char84 is where the pipe starts before the export-csv

can anybody advise me on what ive done wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-VM | where { (Get-NetworkAdapter -vm $_.name).NetworkName -eq "vlan13_VM" } | select Name | export-csv -path c:\scripts\vlans.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or if you want to keep the `foreach` structure, either

...use `Out-File` instead of `Export-CSV`

```
foreach ( $vm in (Get-VM) ) { if ( (Get-NetworkAdapter -vm $vm.name).NetworkName -eq "vlan13_VM" ) {$vm.name | out-file c:\scripts\vlans.csv -Append} }
```

...or collect the list in a hashtable and convert to objects as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19450616)

```
$out = @()
foreach ( $vm in (Get-VM) ) { if ( (Get-NetworkAdapter -vm $vm.name).NetworkName -eq "vlan13_VM" ) {$out += $vm.name} }
$out | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}} | Export-CSV -path c:\scripts\vlans.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($vm in (get-vm)){
  if (Get-NetworkAdapter -vm $vm.name |?{$_.NetworkName -eq "vlan13_VM"})
  {$vm.name | export-csv -path c:\scripts\vlans.csv -NoTypeInformation -append }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. i gave that a try and it came back with an error saying

export-CSV : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'append' at c:\scripts\checkvlan.ps1:3 char:79

Comment: -append is not recognized? 
Then Try to following line instead:
{$vm.name | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation >> c:\scripts\vlans.csv }

Comment: ok tried that line and it created a csv file with some txt inside.. but not server names.. all it has is

Length 15
Length 10
Length 9

and so on... 48 lines of it...

Comment: What about
{$vm | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation >> c:\scripts\vlans.csv }

Comment: nope that didnt work either... that created a csv file containing lots of random info.. looks a lot like the notes/annotations on the vms