# query user /server:$SERVER | export-csv doesn't return the loggedon users

Tags: csv, powershell

When I try to export the logged on users in powershell to a CSV file, I'm getting the length of the result instead of the actual result.

This is the command I use:
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> query user /server:$SERVER | Export-csv test.csv

this returns:
"Length"
"75"
"81"

When I try to export it to a TXT file, it works, but I can't use txt files.
This is what  the TXT output looks like:

USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME

>administrator         console             1  Active      none   24/05/2016 12:53

how can I get the actual logged on users in the CSV file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export-CSV exports length but not name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450616/export-csv-exports-length-but-not-name)

Comment: Paste any important text into the body of your question.  Nobody wants to click through to a screenshot just to read your command line or file contents.

Comment: I tried the methods there. But I either just got an empty CSV, or just a txt formatted CSV.

Comment: You are mixing powershell with the query.exe, which wont work (that easy). Either you parse the output of query.exe or you query your SQL Server directly from Powershell.

Comment: @Martin It's not about querying a Sql Server but listing RDP sessions via [Terminal Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490801.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, was mixing up things. So, just replace the SQL-stuff with rdp/ts pession-stuff.