# Find Machines Registered In Multiple DataStores

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, datastore, vsphere, powercli

I would like to find all the machines that are registered to multiple data stores. I'm thinking of iterating through each data store and finding the vmx paths of each of the machines then finding the ones that have vmx paths in multiple data stores. Not really sure if this would be the correct way to do this, any help would be appreciated on best practice to complete this task, thanks. :)

(Using powershell and vshpere)

Comment: what have you tried? you probably want to start with the vm object.

Comment: Just working on some code that gets all vmx paths from all my machines 
  (get-vm | Get-View | %{$_.Config.Files.VmPathName} | Sort) . Can get the data to be printed in powercli but now trying to figure out why they are saving to a csv file as length instead of the actual path names.

Comment: @MichaelJohnston The reason you only see length in the CSV is because it is the only property in the string object. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450616/export-csv-exports-length-but-not-name).

Comment: I'm not sure what other info you want from the VM view, but `get-vm | get-harddisk | select parent, filename` would probably be a little easier to work with.

Comment: @brendan62269 just need the VMX file path to check which data store the machine was in. Both those commands run at about the same speed in my tests and retrieve the same info.

Comment: Thanks @persistent13, fixed this issue now :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "registered"? To my knowledge, every VM object has a singular VMX file. It's a 1:1 relationship, so the command where you're pulling out the VmPathName is only going to pull back 1 item.

Comment: Also, you could skip piping all your VMs through with the following line: `Get-VM | @{N='VmPathName';E={$_.ExtensionData.Config.Files.VmPathName}}`

Comment: Sorry, last comment... If you're looking for speed, drop `Get-VM` as a whole and do the whole command through `Get-View`: `Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine -Property Config.Files.VmPathName | select @{N='VmPathName';E={$_.Config.Files.VmPathName}}` In my environment, I used measure-command against your line of code and it took 3.3 seconds which dropped to 2.7 seconds with only Get-VM and then down to .7 seconds using Get-View exclusively.

Comment: When running my code, we found that quite a few machines had vmx files registered to multiple data stores. This is what we wanted to find as they will cause problems. Thanks @Kyle Ruddy , the Get view.... is faster, will make things speed up for the future :)