# Get-ADGroupMember Output Formatting

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I will have to alter the output to make it a true csv that can contain commas in values. I'd like to output to a Csv file. I'm having trouble with the syntax. I am using a script like below.

2 - How can I get DisplayName instead of name  as output ?

The logic of script : The first row are the groups exported to the CSV. Store this list into an array.

The next rows will be the iteration of members of the group [1], [2], [3], etc until you reached the maximum length of the group that has the most members. At each iteration, export-CSV that row to the CSV. If there is no member, then don't forget to leave commas.

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like "SSL_VPN_*"}
$keys = @()      # List of groups that are used as keys
$data = @{}      # Hashtable with key being group name and value being list of samaccountnames
$output = @()    # Array of lines for the csv output
$mostmembers = 0 # The number of members of the largest group

# Iterate through the groups, create a list of members associated
foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember $group.name -recursive
    $sams = @()

    foreach ($member in $members) { $sams += $member.samaccountname }

    if ($sams.length -gt $mostmembers) {$mostmembers = $sams.length}

    $keys += $group.name
    $data[$group.name] = $sams
}

#$data | ft -auto

# Now output the data with each group getting a column
# BUG: This did not work as expected, so I built a list of keys manually.
#$keys = $data.Keys

# Header row (bug: commas in a group name would cause problems)
$output += $keys -join ","

# Build each row
for ($rownum = 0; $rownum -lt $mostmembers; $rownum++)
{
    $row = @()
    for ($col = 0; $col -lt $keys.count; $col++)
    {
        # I had to spell this out because my head was hurting, but this could be made more succinct.
        $group = $keys[$col]
        $users = $data[$group]

        if ($users.count -gt $rownum) # This means there is a valid value, hopefully
        {
            $row += $users[$rownum]
        }
        else
        { $row += "" }
    }
    $output += $row -join ","
}

$output  | Export-csv -path "c:\temp\test.csv"  -NTI
```

Output :

```
"Length"
"414"
"160"
"156"
"150"
"134"
"139"
"108"
"120"
"122"
"97"
"102"
"96"
"108"
"97"
"99"
"87"
"83"
"73"
"91"
"76"
"61"
"74"
"76"
"72"
"64"
"58"
"49"
"45"
"54"
"49"
"60"
"49"
"57"
"49"
"51"
"64"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export-CSV exports length but not name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450616/export-csv-exports-length-but-not-name)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if I got what you need. But if I got you right you could start with something like this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'SSL_VPN_*'" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Group = $_.Name
            Members = $Members.sAMAccountName
            count = $Members.sAMAccountName.count
        }
    }
```

This way you get the group, the members and the member count. You can pipe it to whatever further step you need. (Sort-Object, Export-CSV ... )