# Exporting data in object to single cell in csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel

I need to export the data stored in the Name section of the following object to a SINGLE CELL in a csv.

```
$localp = Get-Printer | where Shared -eq $false
```

But whenever I do this:

```
$localp.Name | export-csv -path "test.csv"
```

I get this:

#TYPE System.String
Length
18
29
22
3
9

Comment: I get the same strange behavior. changing your command to $localp | select name | export-csv -Path test.csv works though.

Comment: looks like this might be by design. Using dotted notation returns a [string] object whos only property is length. Using the select method returns a CimInstance object whos only property is Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to want a header and a single cell,
IMO that isn't a proper csv file.

How should the printers be seperated from one another?

This line:

```
('"{0}"' -f ((Get-Printer | where Shared -eq $false).Name -join ',')
```

creates a double quoted text like this one:

```
"Send To OneNote 2016,Microsoft XPS Document Writer,Microsoft Print to PDF,Fax"
```

You could write to a file with `Set-Content`

```
$Printers = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Printers = (Get-Printer | where Shared -eq $false).Name -join ','}
$Printers |Export-Csv '.\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Will produce a file:

```
PS> Get-Content .\test.csv
"Printers"
"Send To OneNote 2016,Microsoft XPS Document Writer,Microsoft Print to PDF,Fax"
```

---

**EDIT after changing to**

```
-join "`n"
```

```
PS> $printers

Printers
--------
Send To OneNote 2016...

PS> $printers|fl

Printers : Send To OneNote 2016
           Microsoft XPS Document Writer
           Microsoft Print to PDF
           Fax

PS> $printers |export-csv .\test.csv -notype
PS> gc .\test.csv
"Printers"
"Send To OneNote 2016
Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Microsoft Print to PDF
Fax"
```

Comment: The header is hardcoded, as I'm getting over 50 different groups of objects, and need to export the data from each object to it's own cell(list of printers in one cell, list of installed apps in another, etc.)

Comment: Is there any way to join them with a newline?

Comment: which variant?  `-join "\`n"`

Comment: LotPings that just cuts everything off after the first printer name

Comment: Only if you output it the wrong way, see changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$localp | Select-Object Name | Export-Csv -Path "test.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450616/export-csv-exports-length-but-not-name) answer by [Ansgar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers),

> `Export-Csv` exports a table of object properties and their values.
>   Since your script is producing string objects, and the only property
>   they have is length, that's what you got.

Comment: That worked! The problem now is that it outputs each of the names to their own row, rather than a single cell, which I need it to do. It also includes the "name" field, which I don't need