# import-csv, add values, export-csv results in file (results in length?)

Tags: powershell

The goal is for me to be able to take the values from csv1 and update them to csv2 where there is a match found based on a column value of id. I can see with the output the values are updating, but when I try to export it to a csv file I get the following...

```
"Length"
"60"
"60"
"60"
"60"
```

Here is the code.

```
$inputCsv = Import-CSV './get_values.csv' -delimiter ","
$updateCsv = Import-CSV './set_values.csv' -delimiter ","
$output = $updateCsv | ForEach-Object {
    # Matching value
    $id = $_.id

    # Row of values found in 2nd file matching value from first file
    $rowFound = $inputCsv|Where-object "ID" -EQ $id #

    # Columns to update values
    if($rowFound -ne $Null -and $rowFound -ne ''){
        $_.email = $rowFound.Email
        Write-Output $_.email
        $_.firstname = $rowFound.FirstName
        Write-Output $_.firstname
        $_.lastname = $rowFound.LastName
        Write-Output $_.lastname
    Write-Output "------------------------------------------------------------"
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv 'C:\scripts\powershell\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

I've tried the solutions from here: [Export-CSV exports length but not name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450616/export-csv-exports-length-but-not-name)

But I wasn't able to get any of them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you export raw string values, rather than structured objects - `Export-Csv` tries to discover the properties of the input objects, and strings only have one property - the length.

Change the loop body to modify `$_`, and then output `$_` at the very end - don't try to output anything else in between:

```
$output = $updateCsv | ForEach-Object {
    # Matching value
    $id = $_.id

    # Row of values found in 2nd file matching value from first file
    $rowFound = $inputCsv | Where-object "ID" -EQ $id #

    # Columns to update values
    if($rowFound){
        $_.email = $rowFound.Email
        $_.firstname = $rowFound.FirstName
        $_.lastname = $rowFound.LastName
    }

    # output the (perhaps modified) object, nothing else
    $_
}
```

Comment: thanks, and not having `write-output...` in between fixed it also.